# How good are the tools to migrate to and from Team System?

Tags: svn, migration, cruisecontrol.net

I was wondering if anyone tried migrating between TS and SVN/CC. 
What I mean by migrating is importing and exporting the repository between source control systems without losing the history.

How good are the tools to migrate to and from VSTS?

I am also interested in knowing any opinion regarding using Team System from users of SVN and continuous integration.

EDIT:
Assume I need the history, otherwise why use a SCM?

Comment: should also be tagged with SCM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tfs2svn... worked great for a project with 1200 TFS changesets.  It was a bit fussy to setup when svn authentication is enabled, but otherwise great.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a totally expert in team system but I found the recent dotnetrocks show on team server to be really interesting:

http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=373

I think it might hold some information that could be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

In a [recent episode of DotNetRocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=373) Brian Randell and Martin Woodward are of the opinion that in adopting a new Source Control / SCM system you're probably better off starting from a clean slate (begin with the most recent release and don't try to migrate history, and use the original system for read-only viewing of change history / blame).

Their discussion was focussed on Visual Source Safe rather than SVN and clearly the migration from/to SVN won't be nearly so problematic but I still think it's good advice. Ask yourself the question "how often do I *really* need the history?". Is it more work than justifies the benefit? Are you just making a rod for your own back? (...insert metaphor here...)

**Update:** whoa! someone just gave [exactly the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749/migrating-to-team-system-from-svn-cruise-controlnet-and-back#71859) at the same time as me - spooky!

Comment: Nice, overview of that episode! dotnetrocks certainly does do exactly what it says on the tin :)